# Generate & Email report from Oracle Forms 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-forms

I generate a report in PDF through passing of parameters from Oracle Forms 11g. I have a requirement to email the same report automatically as well. Following is the part of forms where I have passed on the parameters.

```
pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata1'); 
add_parameter(pl_id, 'FDT', TEXT_PARAMETER,  :a);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'TDT', TEXT_PARAMETER,  :b);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'VC', TEXT_PARAMETER, :e);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'SYS_DATE', TEXT_PARAMETER, :f);
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'FILE');
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESFORMAT',TEXT_PARAMETER,'PDF');
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESNAME',TEXT_PARAMETER,'C:\Downloads\abc.pdf');
```

Now a copy of report is saved in C:\Downloads folder as well as its shown in browser.

I use the following procedure to send current data shown in Forms via emails.

```
create or replace procedure send4 (p_sender IN VARCHAR2, p_recipient IN VARCHAR2, p_subject IN VARCHAR2, p_message IN VARCHAR2)
IS
crlf         VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
l_mailhost VARCHAR2(255) := <IP ADDRESS>;
v_connection             UTL_SMTP.connection;

BEGIN
V_CONNECTION := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
utl_smtp.Helo(V_CONNECTION, l_mailhost);
utl_smtp.Mail(V_CONNECTION, p_sender);
utl_smtp.Rcpt(V_CONNECTION, p_recipient);
utl_smtp.Data(V_CONNECTION,
'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
'From: '   || p_sender || crlf ||
'Subject: '|| p_subject || crlf ||
'To: '     || p_recipient || crlf ||
'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf ||   -- Use MIME mail standard
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
' name="file.txt"'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
' filename="attachment.txt"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf || -- Content of attachment
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND--'         -- End MIME mail
);
UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
EXCEPTION
WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;
```

1. Can I email the Report generated directly? I tried passing the parameter 'MAIL' and 'Email address' in destype and desname but I am guessing there is some settings need to be done?

OR

2. How can I use the email procedure to send the said report as attachment?

OR

3. How can I copy the report pdf generated in user's PC to a specific directory at server? Because I have one separate procedure for email where I can mail PDFs from server directly. User has Windows PC while server is LINUX.

OR

4. Generate report in PDF format at server directly so I could use the procedure (#3 point) to email it?

I am posting this here in Database Administrators because I believe there needs to be a database level configuration done (developers have not been able to help). Sorry if its a wrong forum to post.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a file from filesystem like this:

```
FUNCTION GetFile(FolderName IN VARCHAR2, FileName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB IS

    xbfile   BFILE; 
    xblob    BLOB; 
    destOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    srcOffset INTEGER := 1; 

BEGIN 
    xbfile := BFILENAME (FolderName, FileName); 
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN (xbfile); 
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xblob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);    
    DBMS_LOB.LOADBLOBFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => xblob, 
        src_bfile => xbfile, 
        amount => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(xbfile), 
        dest_offset => destOffset, 
        src_offset => srcOffset); 

    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(xbfile); 

    RETURN xblob; 

END GetFile;
```

In order to access filesystem you must create a DIRECTORY (if not already exists):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY PDF_REPORTS AS 'C:\Downloads';
```

In my application I use this generic package to send mails:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Mailing AS

PRIORITY_HIGH           CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
PRIORITY_NORMAL         CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
PRIORITY_LOW            CONSTANT INTEGER := 5;

MIME_MIXED              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'multipart/mixed;';
MIME_TEXT               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'text/plain;';
MIME_HTML               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'text/html;';  

PROCEDURE SendMail(
    Subject IN VARCHAR2, 
    Message IN OUT CLOB, 
    ToMail IN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE,   
    FromMail IN VARCHAR2, FromName IN VARCHAR2,
    PRIORITY IN INTEGER DEFAULT PRIORITY_NORMAL,
    FileName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
    MimeType IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT MIME_TEXT, --> determines the MIME-Type of binary attachment "BinAttachment"
    TxtAttachment IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL, 
    BinAttachment IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL);


END Mailing;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Mailing AS

PROCEDURE SendMail(
    Subject IN VARCHAR2, 
    Message IN OUT CLOB, 
    ToMail IN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE,   
    FromMail IN VARCHAR2, FromName IN VARCHAR2,
    PRIORITY IN T_MAIL_PRIORITY DEFAULT PRIORITY_NORMAL,
    FileName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
    MimeType IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT MIME_TEXT,
    TxtAttachment IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL, 
    BinAttachment IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL) IS

    MIME_BOUNDARY           CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := '====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====';

    con UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
    ret UTL_SMTP.REPLY;
    Charset VARCHAR2(20);
    Footer VARCHAR2(1000);
    Recipients VARCHAR2(1000);

    LobLen PLS_INTEGER;
    amount PLS_INTEGER := 8192;
    BUFFER VARCHAR2(16384);
    OFFSET PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    isHTML BOOLEAN := REGEXP_LIKE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Message, 1000, 1), '(< *html)|(< *body)', 'i');

BEGIN

    SELECT UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE)
    INTO Charset
    FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
    WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

    -- setup mail header
    con := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.HELO(con, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_DOMAIN'));
    ret := UTL_SMTP.MAIL(con, FromMail);
    FOR i IN ToMail.FIRST..ToMail.LAST LOOP
        Recipients := Recipients ||ToMail(i)||',';
        ret := UTL_SMTP.RCPT(con, ToMail(i));
    END LOOP;
    ret := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(con);

    IF REGEXP_LIKE(FromName, '^[ -~]+$') THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'From: "'||FromName||'" <'||FromMail||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ELSE
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'From: =?UTF-8?B?'|| UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE(FromName, NULL, UTL_ENCODE.BASE64) ||'?= <'||FromMail||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF; 
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'To: '||REGEXP_REPLACE(Recipients, ',$')||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(Subject, '^[ -~]+$') THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Subject: '||Subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ELSE
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE(Subject, NULL, UTL_ENCODE.BASE64), CHR(13), NULL), CHR(10), NULL) ||'?='||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Date: '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss TZHTZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')||UTL_TCP.CRLF);  
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'X-Priority: '||PRIORITY||UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    IF FileName IS NOT NULL THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Mime-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-Type: '||MIME_MIXED||' boundary="'||MIME_BOUNDARY||'"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'This is a multipart message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    -- Append common footer to mail 
    Footer := 'Message from '||SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_NAME')||' sent at '||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
    IF isHTML THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-type: '||MIME_HTML||' charset='||Charset || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        Message := REPLACE(message, '</body>', '<p>'||Footer||'</p></body>');
    ELSE 
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-type: '||MIME_TEXT||' charset='||Charset || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    -- Mail Body
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Message);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(Message, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(BUFFER));
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;   
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    IF NOT isHTML THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, Footer);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    IF FileName IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- Mail Attachment
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-Type: '||MimeType||' name="'||Filename||'"'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'||Filename||'"'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);

        OFFSET := 1;
        IF TxtAttachment IS NOT NULL THEN
            UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);                         
            LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(TxtAttachment);
            LOOP
                EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
                DBMS_LOB.READ(TxtAttachment, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
                UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(BUFFER));
                OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
            END LOOP;
        ELSIF BinAttachment IS NOT NULL THEN
            amount := 48; -- must be a whole multiple of 3
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);            
            LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(BinAttachment);
            LOOP
                EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
                DBMS_LOB.READ(BinAttachment, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
                UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(BUFFER));
                OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
            END LOOP;       
        END IF;
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY||'--' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    -- finish mail
    ret := UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(con);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.QUIT(con);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
        UTL_SMTP.QUIT(con);
END SendMail;

END Mailing;
/
```

It provides some extras:

- You can optionally attach a file (txt or binary, but only one file is supported)
- `From` and `Subject` may contain Non-ASCII characters like öäü (of course the mail Body may also)
- Multiple recipients
- Automatically use correct character set from database
- Automatically detects plain-text or HTML mail body
- Common footer to indicate mail

Then you can call the function like

```
DECLARE
   pdf BLOB;
   Message CLOB := 'Some message text';
BEGIN
   pdf := GetFile('PDF_REPORTS','abc.pdf');

Mailing.SendMail(
    Subject => 'The Subject', 
    Message => Message, 
    ToMail => VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE('name@domain.net'),    
    FromMail => 'oracle@domain.net', 
    FromName => 'DB User: '||USER,
    FileName => 'abc.pdf',
    BinAttachment => pdf,
    MimeType => 'application/pdf' );

END;
```